# Design Issue: Two roles for a class. First for instances creating and the other for types

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

Consider this class diagram:

```
 +--------+     * +------------------+ * afraid-of             +------------+
 | Garden |------>|    Animal        |<------------------------| Baby       |
 +--------+       +------------------+                         +------------+
                        ^
                        |
                 +----------+------+
                 |                 |
          +------+------+   +------+-----+
          | Cat         |   | Wolf       |
          +-------------+   +------------+
```

Animal has two roles:

1. They will be walking around the garden (Class Instance)
2. The baby is afraid of some animals (Class Type)

What baby should keep? One instance of each animal it's afraid of? (sounds like poor design)
The type name? (I always try to avoid refactoring)

How should this be solved? (I'm using C# and I mention it only at the end because I hope there is a general, language-free design pattern or idea here)

Thanks

Comment: I have failed to understand why there are close votes on this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If babies are always afraid of the same animals, you don't have to keep anything.
You can have a method:

```
public bool IsAfraid(Animal animal)
{
    return animal is Wolf;
}
```

If babies are afraid of different animals in different places and times, you should make every animal have a property AnimalType (flag enum). The baby will then have a property AfraidOf, of type AnimalType.
And then, checking if you are afraid of an animal is simple:

```
bool afraid = this.AfraidOf.HasFlag(animal.AnimalType);
```

Finally, you should probably have different types of linking to different classes for different types of relationships in your schema (Contains, Inherits, Afraid of).

Comment: Good answer...Personally I'd us the enum flag route in this case.

Comment: I would also go that way. It's more extendable and logical.

Comment: But then we have an enum that is duplicated to the classes. Every time I will want to add an animal to my software, I will have to update both the enum and add a new class.

Comment: Yes, this happens in many systems. I agree it isn't perfect but it is the popular way to do it. Adding an enum member and an enum property isn't the end of the world. You're making a new class after all.

Comment: OR, you COULD have the property inherited from base Animal, which sets it in ctor according to "is" operator. Then all the animal typing logic will sit in one place. Still the same amount of actions for a new animal, but it's neater.

Comment: it seems like I'm going for your solution, adding a function at the baby class (baby never changes its fears):

        public bool IsAfraidOf(Animal animal)
        {
            if (animal is Wolf)
                return true;
            else if (animal is Cat)
                return false;
            else
                return false;
        }

Comment: I'd go for a switch already, even though right now it's very small.

Answer (score 0):

A `Baby` can have a list of animals he/she is afraid of. I would specify independent methods to add and remove animals from the list coz with time passing some animals can be removed or added. It is possible to change the list of animals directly through the property, but I would prefer specific methods in this case.

```
public class Animal { }
public class Cat : Animal { }
public class Wolf : Animal { }

public class Baby
{
    public List<Animal> ScaryAnimalsList { get; private set; }

    public Baby()
    {
        ScaryAnimalsList = new List<Animal>();
    }

    public void AddAnimalToScaryList(Animal animal)
    {
        ScaryAnimalsList.Add(animal);
    }

    public void RemoveAnimalFromScaryList(Animal animal)
    {
        if (ScaryAnimalsList.Contains(animal))
            ScaryAnimalsList.Remove(animal);
    }

    public bool IsAffraidOf(Animal animal)
    {
        return ScaryAnimalsList.Contains(animal);
    }
}
```

And this is how to use it

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Wolf wolf = new Wolf();

        var babyJo = new Baby();
        babyJo.AddAnimalToScaryList(wolf);
        babyJo.IsAffraidOf(wolf);   //true
        babyJo.IsAffraidOf(cat);    //false

        var babySam = new Baby();
        babySam.AddAnimalToScaryList(wolf);
        babySam.AddAnimalToScaryList(cat);
        babySam.IsAffraidOf(wolf);   //true
        babySam.IsAffraidOf(cat);    //true

        var babyBob = new Baby();
        babyBob.IsAffraidOf(wolf);   //false
        babyBob.IsAffraidOf(cat);    //false
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. your solution won't help me solve my problem since I have many instances. Add to your main function another Wolf instance, wolf1 for example. Now, babyJo.IsAfraidOf(wolf1) will return false even though it's afraid of wolf. Adding every instance to the list is too much.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add features to your animals.

```
public class Animal
{
    public virtual bool EatsSmallChildren { get { return false; } }
}
```

and then your babies can check if the animal is scary instead of whether the baby is afraid of it.

This puts the burden on your animal class, and introduces some conceptual coupling, but is also very straight-forward and easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: thanks, but in my case, there are millions of classes that are afraid of an Animal (Baby, Student, Alien, etc)